# RuntimeException at app startup due to com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-appcompat

I have crash that in my app that I have never managed to reproduce myself but that I know happens occasionally because I can see that in the Google Analytics console.

The crash happens as the user launches the application. An exception is raised when I call setContentView in my Activity derived class

```
H:0kfgjhA== T:main RuntimeException(Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mydomain·myapp/com.mydomain·myapp.activity.history.HistoryActivit) Cause: NotFoundException(Resource ID #0x7f020134) S:24 00:Resources:android.content.res.Resources.getValue:1274 
01:Resources:android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable:797 
02:Context:android.content.Context.getDrawable:402 
03:ToolbarWidgetWrapper:com.android.internal.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setIcon:320 
04:ActionBarOverlayLayout:com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setIcon:738 
05:PhoneWindow:com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setDefaultIcon:1623 
06:Activity:android.app.Activity.initWindowDecorActionBar:2139 
07:Activity:android.app.Activity.setContentView:2154 
09:MyActivity:com.mydomain·myapp.activity.MyActivity.onCreate:121
```

The resource that I set in the call to setContentView is an empty FrameLayout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:id="@+id/content_frame">

</FrameLayout>
```

The resource that the Resource class cannot find is the application icon (ID #0x7f020134). That icon is only referenced at one place and that is in the manifest file

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/my_launcher_icon"
.../>
```

It seems as this defect appeared after we included the appcompat support library v7. That is done in the manifest file (in the dependencies section)

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

Does anybody know anything about this problem? How can I fix it?

According to Google Analytics the crash seems to happen only on 5.0, 5.01 and 5.1.1 devices. And it is not a very frequent crash and it is very stochastic.

Thanks
Ola, Sweden

Edit:

The oncreate function looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_trackid);
}
```

Comment: Please post the code of `onCreate` in `MyActivity` and xml used in that activity

Comment: Make sure image you are showing in right place ?
E.g. if you have put image in drawalbe/xhdpi folder and run app in other than xhdpi device then this exception for sure will occure.

Comment: The appicon exists in all the drawable folders (xhdpi, xxhdpi mdpi etc) and has the right sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this  line in application tag

android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

Like:

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/my_launcher_icon"
```

/>

Comment: Well our app tag already takes use of another theme and it looks like this:
    <application
            android:name="App name"
            android:allowBackup="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/my_launcher_icon"
            android:label="@string/application_name"
            android:theme="@style/TransparentTheme"
            android:supportsRtl="true">